# Image width not correct after scaling

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am doing a little project on the canvas where I have a map that I can zoom and pan, which works very well so far.

Now to my problem, after I zoom in I don't want the image to be able to be dragged more than the edges of the image (never show anything but the image on canvas).
This works good for the top and left side of the image (X and Y coords can never be more than 0 (top of canvas).

But for the right and bottom parts, I need to calculate the new width and height of the scaled image and say that X and Y can never be less than canvas width and the excess of the image that is outside of the canvas.

This does not appear to be correct, made an image to illustrate since my explaining is not so good, Black rectangle being my canvas and red being my image.

My guesses are that it is not as easy as taking image width*scale for new width or that it has to do with the offset of my canvas, tried to calculate with that as well but the offset is only8px and does not seem to be the full extent of the problem as if I zoom more the problem gets bigger.

Thankfull for any help and sorry for the long and weird explanation =)

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A37k0.gif)

```
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown);
function mouseDown(e){
    mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX);
    mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY);
    lastX = mouseX;
    lastY = mouseY;
    down = true;
}

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove);

function mouseMove(e){
    if (!down){
        return;
    }
    mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX);
    mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY);

    dx = mouseX - lastX;
    dy = mouseY - lastY;

    x = dx;
    y = dy;

    if (x>0){
        x = 0;
    }
    if (y>0){
        y = 0;
    }
    draw(x,y);
}

canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp);
function mouseUp(){
    down = false;
    lastX = mouseX;
    lastY = mouseY;
    ctx.fillText(mouseX,25,50);
    ctx.fillText(dx,25,75);
}

function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,1525,850);
    ctx.scale(scaleY,scaleX);
    ctx.drawImage(img,x,y,1375,850);
    ctx.fillRect(x+688,y+425,10,10);
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1,0,0);
}
//Never zoom more then 2,5
function zoomIN(){
    scaleY = scaleY + 0.1;
    scaleX = scaleX + 0.1;
    if (scaleY >= 2.5){
        scaleY = 2.5;
        scaleX = 2.5;
    }
    draw(scaleY,scaleX,x,y);
}
//Never zoom less then 1
function zoomOUT(){
    scaleY = scaleY - 0.1;
    scaleX = scaleX - 0.1;
    if (scaleY <= 1){
        scaleY = 1;
        scaleX = 1;
    }
    draw(scaleY,scaleX,x,y);
}
```

Comment: Your `draw` method does not have any parameters, even tho you call it with them. Also you are calling it once with `x, y` as first and second parameter, but later you have `scaleX` and `scaleY` instead...

Comment: Yes, it is alot of weird stuff in the code that i added and removed for debugging purposes, didnt clean Everything out Before posting here. But the problem remains, why is the calculated width not correct, ie 1375*1,1 = 1512,5 but on the acctual canvas its 1501...

Comment: Would be good to provide working jsbin with given issue

Comment: Thx for taking time to help me, here it is: https://jsbin.com/kulugixecu/1/edit      , press zoom in and the Picture shows then move it by clicking and dragging until the edge of the image is at the right edge of the right side canvas, now the original width 1375 is scaled by 1,1 and should be 1512,5 but add the X value that i added in the canvas being the origin of where to start drawing the image it should be X + 1375 = 1512,5 but it is not, x being a negative is not important in this case..